# How to display entities taken from XML with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, entities

There MUST be an easy way to do that! I didn't want to ask this question again if somebody already asked it but I couldn't find something similar in this site... anyway :

So I have a XML file :

```
<marker>This is a test &amp; it&#039;s fun. &eacute;</marker>
```

So when I read this XML file with Javascript, I want to put it in a text input of a form, but it comes out with the & amp; etc instead of :

```
This is a test & it's fun. é
```

I really don't understand why I'm having so much problem finding a way to show the text right... Don't we all have the same problem with XML??? Help me!! In PHP, this would be sooo easy :(

Thanks a bunch in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your XML isn't well-formed, so you probably isn't reading it as xml but plain text

Through DOM, you'll get &amp; and &#039; correctly, but an error on &eacute; (undefined character entity)

**EDIT**

Since you don't have problems opening that file as XMLDOMDocument, you should be able to run following code into your browser. Make sute to create a SPAN tag to display that text:

```
var text = xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//marker").text;
document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0].innerHTML = text;
alert(text);
```

Comment: This is not my full XML file. I don't have an error while loading the file, I'm just not displaying it correctly in my form... And I need to know how to make the &eacute; => é to make it readable

Comment: so you're opening that file as XMLDOMDocument and no errors happens, right?